# JQuery->event Continue

Tags: jquery

I am binding a mousedown on a button like this:

```
$(".save_btn").bind("mousedown", {PID: ParticipantID}, LicenseCheck);
```

In the LicenseCheck function, I'm validating some fields and if the validation fails, I 
call event.preventDefault, call a function to show an error message and return false;
If the validation succeeds, I return true. But the event doesn't continue, it's almost like it just stops.

```
function LicenseCheck(event) {
    var PID       = event.data.PID;
    var showError = false;
    var c         = null;

    if($.trim($("#lname_"+PID).val()) != "") {
        if($.trim($("#ln_"+PID).val()) == "") {
            showError = true;
            c = $("#ln_"+PID);
        } 
    } else {
        if($.trim($("#lname_"+PID).val()) == "") {
            showError = true;
            c = $("#lname_"+PID);
        } 
    }
    if ($('input[type=radio][name^="lt_'+PID+'"]:checked').length == 0) {
        showError = true;
        c = $('input[type=radio][id^="lt_'+PID+'"]')[0];
    }
    if(showError) {
        ShowFormError(c, PID);
        event.preventDefault;
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

function ShowFormError(control, PID) {
    $parent   = $("#p_div_"+PID);
    var pos   = control.position();
    $arrows   = $("<div>", {"class": "formErrorArrow"})
        .append($("<div>", {"class": "line10", html: '<!-- -->'}))
        .append($("<div>", {"class": "line9", html: '<!-- -->'}))
        .append($("<div>", {"class": "line8", html: '<!-- -->'}))
        .append($("<div>", {"class": "line7", html: '<!-- -->'}))
        .append($("<div>", {"class": "line6", html: '<!-- -->'}))
        .append($("<div>", {"class": "line5", html: '<!-- -->'}))
        .append($("<div>", {"class": "line4", html: '<!-- -->'}))
        .append($("<div>", {"class": "line3", html: '<!-- -->'}))
        .append($("<div>", {"class": "line2", html: '<!-- -->'}))
        .append($("<div>", {"class": "line1", html: '<!-- -->'}));

    $item     = $("<div>",   {"class": "formError hidden", id: "form_error_"+PID})
        .append($("<div>", {"class": "formErrorContent", html: "* This field is required<br>"}))
        .append($arrows);
    $parent.append($item);
    $("#form_error_"+PID).css("top", pos.top-35);
    $("#form_error_"+PID).css("margin-top", 0);
    $("#form_error_"+PID).css("opacity", 0.87);    
    $("#form_error_"+PID).css("left", pos.left+control.width()+-30);
    $("#form_error_"+PID).css("position", "absolute");
    $("#form_error_"+PID).removeClass('hidden');
    $("#form_error_"+PID).bind('click', function() {
        $(this).addClass('hidden');
    });
}
```

How do I make it continue on in what it's supposed to do when it is clicked without the mousedown handler?

Comment: You may want to look into the [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method as a more up-to-date method of working with events in jQuery.

Comment: What do you want to continue to?

Comment: I figured it out, I just have to  trigger the 'click'.

Comment: @Surreal Dreams - We are using 1.7.2, .on() doesn't exist.

Comment: Also, `.css({ 'key' : 'value', 'key' : 'value' });` you can just turn it into one big key/value literal.

Comment: From the .on() docs:  `As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method provides all functionality required for attaching event handlers.`  100% Available to you  :)

Comment: When I have tried it before, I got errors that it didn't exist.

Comment: Thanks @mcpDESIGNS, I'll look into shortening the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(this).trigger('click');
```

before the return true worked like a charm.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information.  The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: Since I was the one that came up with the answer, I didn't want someone to come in and add an answer and make me have to accept it.